# Can't share url using twitter and facebook using UIActivityViewController

Tags: iphone, ios7, uiactivityviewcontroller

Not able to share url in Twitter and Facebook, here is my code :

```
- (IBAction)btnSharePressed:(UIButton *)sender
{

    UIImage *shareImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"toolBar.png"];
    NSString *shareTitle = @"Share Title";
    NSURL *shareUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];

    NSArray *Items = @[shareUrl,shareImage,shareTitle];

    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
                                              initWithActivityItems:Items
                                              applicationActivities:nil];

    [activityVC setValue:shareTitle forKey:@"subject"];

    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Only getting shareTitle content in the Twitter and Facebook post compose box, content of shareUrl is missing, image is rendering perfectly. Please let me know where am i mistaking? thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I got to know that image of url is overlapping with the image which i want to attach, can any one help me how to show url with text link instead of url converted in image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with Code and its share all detail provided ,

I guess your problem is that you are not showing all in share popup, because **image and url are showed owerlapped**,

[image]

Comment: ya i got that image is overlapping, i need to display that url in popup, can you please help me ? @ @Viruss mca

Comment: In facebook ios 7 url show with text,in twitter it overlapped.

Comment: ya problem is in twitter only, do you have any idea to hack this one ?

Comment: @iOSbeginner: sorry right now i have now idea about it, ill let you know if i got something.